# FXML file not opening in SceneBuilder

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have an FXML file: `main-view.fxml` which functions perfectly fine, displaying eveything as expected when run within the project and showing zero errors in IntelliJ's FXML editor. However it is unable to be seen in intelliJ's built-in scene builder or in the standalone one. I've tested my other files and they all seem to be working as expected. I've also uninstalled and reinstalled the standalone scene builder.

I've searched around and I think there's a problem with the root Node or one of my imports but they're all the same as my other files. I've also gone through the entire file and haven't found an issue.

Link to FXML file in question: [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LLNhVwIMXB3fs6EQveuYz7vXZAdpZHnK/view?usp=sharing) (It's very long)

Comment: _It's very long_ strip it down to contain only the part that's not readable by scenebuilder (and still is complete enough, that is would be readable/show up normally!) - that is provide a [mcve]. Also: external references don't exist - c&p the (greatly reduced) fxml here.

Comment: Scenebuilder has stacktrace. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73042778/7587451)

Comment: unable to open it here . netbeans 16 , jdk coretto 17 , ubuntu mate 4-20  64 ,scenebuilder  17  javafx17

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion from [@kleopatra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203657/kleopatra) I was able to find the problem:

It seems I had a closing `<rowConstraints/>` tag without an opening one that didn't impact functionality but caused the file to not open in Scene Builder.

Hopefully this will help those in a similar spot in the future.